# Сложность вставки нового элемента в список

Tags: data-structures, структуры-данных, алгоритм

В однонаправленном списке сложность вставки нового узла в начало и конец есть О(1), так как в контейнере есть указатели на начало и конец соответственно.

Читал, что вставка в середину тоже занимает `О(1)` по времени, но почему? Разве не придется пройтись по всем узлам начиная с первого до текушего чтоб вставить?

Comment: Так вставка подразумевается не по индексу.

Comment: так в том то и дело что раз вставка не по индексу значит придется пройтись по всем узлам от начала до текушего чтобы вставить новый после него, а тут без цикла никак, следовательно сложность линейная будет как минимум, но везде пишут что вставка в середину за О(1) тоесть за одну операцию, я не понимаю почему это так

Comment: @arammis: Не может быть. Вставка в середину `O(index)`, если по индексу, и `O(n)`, если по значению. O(1) только если у вас есть указатель в середину (для однонаправленного списка — на _предыдущий_ элемент).

Comment: Может имеется в виду вставка после определенного элемента?

Comment: @arammis, когда вы вставляете в список элемент, то вам надо указать куда вставлять. это значит, что элемент перед которым надо вставить или после которого у вас есть. функция вставки меняет у одного существующего (указанного в качестве параметра функции) элемента ссылку на "следующий элемент" на "вновь добавляемый". И для добавляемого прописывает ссылку "на след элемент" существующего. Т.е. две операции - константное время. То, что вы считаете o(index) или o(n) - это поиск элемента, а не вставка.

Comment: Например, если у вас идет сортировка списка, то чтоб поменять местами два элемента (которые вы уже сравниваете) вам не надо пробегать весь список заново чтоб найти эти элементы, ссылки на них у вас уже есть

Comment: а откуда берётся указатель, скажемна на конец ?? к примеру если создать список и в цикле и делать mylist.push_back(value) в этом случае тоже константная сложность. Почему ?? здесь же не указывается место вставки добавляемого элемента, а лишь только значение ...

Comment: Место не указывается, указывается элемент после которого нужно вставить новый элемент.

Comment: @nekaneka я понял что если вставлять куда - то в середину то надо указывать индекс и элемент после которого вставлять, тоесть будет О(1) - это понятно, но если вставлять вконец push_back ом сложность почему то опять константная (О(1)), и причем в этой функции указывается только значение и не указывается элемент после которого надо вставлять.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/

Answer (score 4):

[мало места в комментарии]

[@arammis](/users/20380/arammis), вы привели ссылку на описание конкретной реализации в конкретном ЯП. Если вы почитаете непосредственно про [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/), то увидите, что для данной реализации имеется итератор, поэтому и вставка по позиции тоже будет равна константе.
в вопросе у вас описан совсем другой, "сферический" вариант, который рассматривают в вузах, когда рассматриваются все операции над структурами данных и вводятся понятия О-нотации на простых примерах структур. std::list естественно не простая структура, она не для обучения предназначена, а для жизни.

Чтоб окончательно понять почему не O(n) возьмите массив и сравните сколько действий будет для него, и вообще что происходит при вставке. И представьте что вам надо вставить элемент в середину. И проследите какие действия нужно для этого совершить: расширение капасити, если надо, а если таки надо, то может быть придется копировать весь массив на новое место; копирование хвоста массива a[i+1]=a[i]. Тут как раз и возникают O(n), потому что непосредственно операция вставки занимает линейное время. Зато поиск в массиве занимает O(1), а у ванильного списка наоборот.

Посмотрите в википедии по разным структурам данных, указывается отдельно время поиска, вставки в начало/конец, в середину, накладные расходы на хранение и т.д. Вы в вопросе описали не "вставка" = o(1), а "поиск+вставка" = O(n)+O(1) = O(n).

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, в вопросе я подразумевал список из С++, и в тегах обозначил именно этот яп, но теги почему то поменяли. Но это сейчас уже не важно.

Я знаю как организован список, но хотел лишь уточнить нектороые моменты, и вопросе шла речь только а вставке без поиска.

Comment: В качестве уточнения: _поиск_ занимает `O(n)`. Для того, чтобы _найти_ нужный итератор, необходимо затратить `O(n)`. Имея нужный итератор, вставка производится за `O(1)`.

Comment: @arammis, ну будем надеяться объяснение поможет кому-то еще. Если вас интересует конкретная реализация функции вставки по позиции и ее время работы в указанном яп, то либо можно посмотреть исходники, либо подождать других участников, может быть будут другие уточняющие комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего имеется ввиду просто вставка. Вставка в любое место связного списка производится с временной сложностью О(1), ибо нужно просто поменять ссылки. Что касается поиска + вставки, то поиск в связном списке занимает O(n), так что тут два варианта: 1) либо вы реализовали какой-то особенный связной список, где есть еще ссылка на средний элемент (тогда уже и поиск и вставка будут О(1)), либо у вас обычный связной список и вам надо будет пройтись от начала до (Count / 2) и вставить элемент там. Временная сложность поиска составляет O(n / 2) что будет равняться О(n) и вставка как обычно О(1).

Что касается особенного линкед листа со ссылкой на средний элемент - это неэффективно из-за того, что каждый раз у вас после добавления элемента будет снова вычисляться этот средний элемент, то есть связной список с 1000 элементами будет вынужден в худшем случае произвести 1000 + ~500 + 1 итераций, когда обычный список произвел бы 1000 + 1.

Короче, пользы от особенно связного списка нет, ибо мы будем искать этот средний элемент даже тогда, когда он нам не нужен.

Так что все это бред про то что вставка + поиск в середину = О(1). А вот вставка в ЛЮБОЙ участок списка будет составлять О(1).

Пытался разжевать как можно подробнее. Надеюсь было понятно :)